# I have dataframe column with time in integer format, I want to convert it into hours and mins and categorize them into bins

Tags: pandas

The departure time is to be converted to time format and categorize them. ex: 22:30 to 22-23.

[image]

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Does `1907.0` and `1344.0` correspond to `19:07` and `13:44`, respectively?

Comment: Yes 1907.0 corresponds to 19:07

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
# Mock random data
n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DEP_TIME': np.random.randint(0, 24, n) * 100 + np.random.randint(0, 60, n)
})

# Convert DEP_TIME to decimal hours: 22:30 -> 22.5
s = df['DEP_TIME'] // 100 + (df['DEP_TIME'] % 100) / 60

# Now bin them
df['DEP_TIME_RANGE'] = pd.cut(s, bins=range(25), labels=[f'{i}-{i+1}' for i in range(24)])
```

Result:

```
   DEP_TIME DEP_TIME_RANGE
0      2247          22-23
1       105            1-2
2       707            7-8
3      1749          17-18
4      1049          10-11
```